# Python - Converting a list of strings to lowercase using for loops

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a given list of strings to lower-case versions of them using for loops. I am not very knowledgeable about Python and for-loops in general so the following code is a mix of mine and what I found online. It gives me the error "set_lowercase() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given" How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    newList = []
    for name in strings:
        newList.append(name.lower())
    print(newList)
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: You need to show how you call your function `set_lowercase()`. It should be like this: `set_lowercase(['aBC','dEF'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use list comprehensions,

```
new_list = [a.lower() for a in l]
```

do this,

```
 def set_lowercase(strings):
        newList = [a.lower() for a in strings]
        return newList

strings = set_lowercase(strings)
```

Comment: I followed your reply and changed my code to
`def set_lowercase(strings):
    """Replaces each string in the list with its lower-case version"""
    strings = [a.lower() for a in strings]
    print(strings)`
I call this function with `set_lowercase(['aBC','dEF'])` However I dont think this updates the list with the new list (with lower-case strings) so both lists get printed out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To clarify further, I test my code with `strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']
set_lowercase(strings)
print(strings)` And it prints `['right', 'said', 'fred']
['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']`

Comment: the problem is the scope of your python variables. stings printed with lower case are from function and upper case are from outside the function. Try  learning about scope in python. For quick fix, add return strings in your function and and do this strings = set_lowercase(strings)

Comment: Could you please kindly edit my code in my original comment to what it is supposed to look like? It is difficult for me to follow what you are saying because of my lack of experience and knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling

```
set_lowercase("A", "B", "C")
```

pass an actual iterable:

```
set_lowercase(("A", "B", "C"))
```